# Contextual Type AnyObject Cannot Be Used With Array Literal for Coordinates

Tags: ios, iphone, arrays, swift, xcode

I have look into several other different questions posted with the same problem but non of them help answer my question because I am using this for coordinates. I recently upgrade to Swift3 and I got this error "**Contextual Type AnyObject Cannot Be Used With Array Literal**"

So this is how the code looks like where I declare my variable for my coordinates

```
 var coordinates: [AnyObject]!
```

This is the next code where the error occurs, I will replace the numbers with x. I am using the longitude and latitude

```
coordinates = [[xx.xxxxxx, -xxx.xxxxxx],[xx.xxxxxx, -xxx.xxxxxx],[xx.xxxxxx, -xxx.xxxxxx]]
```

And the way I call it is by using for loop which I dont think causes any problem but I'll just post it just in case

```
for i in 0...2
    {
        let coordinate = coordinates[i]}
```

Problem solved by implementing

```
var coordinates: [[Double]]!
```

Comment: Is there some reason you can't declare coordinates as `var coordinates: [[Float]]!` or `var coordinates: [[Double]]!`?

Comment: Why use a 2D array of type `[AnyObject]!`? The compiler has no idea what type the inner arrays should be. In any case, a more appropriate data structure would be an array of structs.

Comment: What is the actual Linker error?

Comment: Linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

ld: framework not found Pods_getCurrentLocation
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change :-

```
import MapKit


class yourController : ...{  

var coordinates: [AnyObject]!
```

To

```
var coordinates = [CLLocationCoordinate2D]()
```

To access a particular `lat` or `long` at a particular index just:-

```
coordinates[your_index].latitude // Latitude

coordinates[your_index].longitude //Longitude
```

**`CLLocationCoordinate2D`** is a struct , much more easily scalable and accessible than array.

Comment: Avoid extending your question's when one is answered , SO has no restriction on posting two questions in one day. Accept this as answer if it solved your issue.:)Happy Coding

Comment: There is more questions, I have more problem implementing different part. Please read the post